# automatically export CSV from googlesheet to our server

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

We have CSV file which is located on our server, https://example.com/thisFIle.csv. That is the exported data from Google sheet. A third party website is fetching the data from that CSV file every 3 mins.

The company that I am working on is in booking business, so their agents are the persons updating the Google sheet, then I will export the data into CSV then upload to our server.

upon searching I learned that there is this google script section in Google sheet. How can I make the process of instead exporting the CSV then upload manually to our server to be automatically using this google script?

Comment: I think that the Spreadsheet can be exported as a CSV file using Google Apps Script. But I cannot understand about ``automatically`` you are thinking. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail situation of ``automatically``?

Comment: is there a way also in google app script that will upload that exported csv(using that google app script) to our server? because the scenario is, some third party system is fetching the data from that csv so we need to make it updated every time there's a changes on google sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that process with Google App Script [1].

Using the methods of the classes in the spreadsheet service [2] and [3], you can obtain the data of the sheet you want having the spreadsheetID (the alphanumeric id that appear inside the url when you open a Google Sheet) . Then loop through the data and parse it to a string in csv format.

With the csv string you can create a blob object [4] that will be sent to the server through a post request using the fetch method [5].

To make your code runs automatically you can use the manual triggers for example, and set them to run every minute or as you need [6].

You have to set your server application to receive the post request and set the request url in the App Script (https://example.com/post as an example). Below is the code I tested until obtain the csvBlob variable:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetID");
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // This represents ALL the data
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var csvStr = "";
  
   // This creates a string of the spreadsheet in CSV format with a trailing comma
   for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
       var row = "";
       for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
           if (values[i][j]) {
              row = row + values[i][j];
           
           row = row + ",";
       
       row = row.substring(0, (row.length-1));
       csvStr += row + "\n";
   } 
  
  //creates de Blob of the csv file
  var csvBlob = Utilities.newBlob(csvStr, 'text/csv', 'example.csv');
  Logger.log(csvBlob.getDataAsString());

  //make a post request to the server (I didn't test this part)
  var formData = {
      'name': 'Bob Smith',
      'email': 'bob@example.com',
      'file': csvBlob
  };
  var options = {
      'method' : 'post',
      'payload' : formData
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://example.com/post', options);
}
```

[1] https://script.google.com/home

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet

[4] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newBlob(Byte,String,String)

[5] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

[6] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: thanks @AndresDuarte! I'll try this and let you know the result